# Invoking groups SCIM API

Tags: wso2, scim

I am using WSO2 IDM server and working on using SCIM API's available.
When I invoked the get groups SCIM API https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Groups, I am getting error in response

```
{
    "Errors": [
        {
            "code": "404",
            "description": "Groups not found in the user store."
        }
    ]
}
```

I created few users and roles under 'PRIMARY' user store.

However I am able to successfully invoke the get users API.
WSO2 Version: 5.11

Please let me know if I am missing configuration.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You have used scim v1 APIs for user and group retrieval.
Can you please try scim2 APIs (This is recommended).

List groups: https://localhost:9443/scim2/Groups

List users: https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users

refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/scim-20-api-definition